# Recursively adding to lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am looking at some hydropower data separated in two dataframes, stations and reservoirs.

df_stations,  df_reservoirs

```
Name Size Number          R_Name R_Size R_number
A   20   1                  W       200      2
B   30   2                  X       300      4
C   30   3                  Y       150      2
D   35   4                  Z       100
```

The columns "Number" and "R_number both reference the powerstation, så reservoir "X" is connected to powerstation 4 as they have the same number. I want to combine these dataframes into one, where the corresponding data is on the same row. Some stations have several reservoirs (some have none), for these I would want a list with the information as I have tried to show below.

df_combined

```
Name Size Number R_Name R_Size R_number
A   20   1
B   30   2   W,Y   200,150   2,2
C   30   3   
D   35   4   X   300   4
```

I have developed a minimal working example (my apologies for poor PEP)

```
import pandas as pd

df_powerstations = pd.DataFrame([['A', 20,1],['B',30,2],['C',30,3],['D',35,4]], columns=['Name','Size','Number'])
df_reservoirs = pd.DataFrame([['W', 200, 2],['X', 300, 4],['Y',150,2],['Z',100, '']], columns=['R_name', 'R_size', 'R_Number'])

R_cols = df_reservoirs.columns.values.tolist()
df_combined = pd.concat([df_powerstations, pd.DataFrame(columns=R_cols)]) # type: pd.DataFrame

for ps_ind, ps_num in enumerate(df_combined['Number']):
    for r_ind, r_ps_num in enumerate(df_reservoirs['R_Number']):
        if ps_num == r_ps_num:
            df_combined.loc[ps_ind, R_cols] = df_reservoirs.loc[r_ind, R_cols].copy()
```

This code will give me the last reservoir with matching number, so only Y for station B. I attempted to use append instead, but this gave me neither error nor results (I no longer have that code).

Would the best solution maybe be to make the lists first and then the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `merge`

```
In [2158]: df_rg = df_reservoirs.groupby('R_Number').apply(
                                  lambda x: x.astype(str).agg(','.join))

In [2159]: df_combined = df_powerstations.merge(df_rg, left_on='Number',
                                                right_index=True,
                                                how='left').fillna('')

In [2164]: df_combined
Out[2164]:
  Name  Size  Number R_name   R_size R_Number
0    A    20       1
1    B    30       2    W,Y  200,150      2,2
2    C    30       3
3    D    35       4      X      300        4
```

---

Details

```
In [2161]: df_rg
Out[2161]:
         R_name   R_size R_Number
R_Number
2           W,Y  200,150      2,2
4             X      300        4
              Z      100
```

Comment: Ah thanks jez! That led me to a further simplification.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem and also made my code faster. I've been told that if I use a for-loop, I'm probably doing something wrong.. Somehow it remains my go-to solution.